# i want to pubslish 3 million lines to Queue. Will JMS queue supports it

Tags: jms

I want to publish 3 million lines(1 jms message = l line) to jms queue. each line is one jms message. so totally i will publish 3 million message. will JMS queue supports this much of large data in Queue?

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned in what time frame you want to publish 3 million messages. 3 million messages to be published in a second or minute or hour or day(s). What is the size of each message? KBs or MBs ? How quickly the published messages are consumed by consumers?

So it depends on a number of such parameters to understand if a JMS provider can handle your requirement or not. It's not a good practice to use queue as database. Messages in queue must be consumed as quickly as possible so that message build up is avoided. Any message build up will affect throughput.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.

You'll need to configure your JMS Provider appropriately, and this can often be tricky (and sometimes the defaults just work).

Typically you configure it to have disk storage for the messages that don't fit in RAM.  You need to make sure you've got enough resource (RAM and disk space) to store everything.

I've had success with ActiveMQ - this page might be useful to you:

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-activemq-to-hold-100s-of-millions-of-queue-messages-.html